# Set default value to Date input in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, date

I am trying to set a default value to the date input field in the lightning record edit form (Today + 90 days). I have done the below code but it is not recognized in MMM d, yyyy format.

```
var someDate = new Date(new Date().getTime()+(90*24*60*60*1000)); //added 90 days to todays date
var mon = this.getMonth(someDate.getMonth()+1);
var dat = someDate.getDate();
var yea = someDate.getFullYear();
var f= mon+' '+dat+', '+yea; //example - Oct 29,2021
```

[image]

How shall I convert this to a proper date format? *this.getMonth* is just translating numbers to equivalent months like 1 - Jan, 2 - Feb

**UPDATE**: Tried the below code as well but still the same issue.

```
    console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { dateStyle: 'medium'}).format(someDate));
```

Comment: The [docs say to set `value` to an ISO 8601 string (YYYY-MM-DD)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation), though that's for a `lightning-input` specifically and I assume you're using `lightning-input-field` which may not work the same way. Is an option here to set the default value at the field-level so that way it's consistent across your org?

Comment: Nope, it's the standard Effective Date on Opportunities and I am not seeing any option to set the default value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried the below solution on Friday didn't seem to work. But on Monday its working suddenly. Hope this will helps others too.

```
var someDate = new Date(new Date().getTime()+(90*24*60*60*1000)); //added 90 days to todays date
return someDate.toISOString();
```

Also for reference adding a screenshot for the record edit form field

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I may be rehashing the above but FWIW I was struggling with this "Your entry does not match the allowed format MMM d, yyyy." error as well. It was occurring every time I tried setting the date in my controller (JS) file. I tried fussing with date-format attributes (short, medium, etc) on my lightning-input control but that did not help. The below (primarily what is describe above) is how I finally got past the error:

HTML:

`<lightning-input type="date" name="myDate" value={myDate} label="My Date"></lightning-input>`

JS:

`this.myDate= new Date('7/4/2022').toISOString();`